# How to integrate HTML and JavaScript into a WordPress page?

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress

I am a relatively new WordPress developer, and I am running into difficulty with embedding html and JavaScript on to a page.

I am redesigning a website for a company, and they would like me to integrate a calculator function from their old site, which is [here](http://sgh.com.au/generator-power-calculator.php)

I have viewed the source code for it and transferred everything over except for their old styling information. The calculator displays fine, but the "Calculate" button does not do anything. I've combed through the code and am scratching my head on where to begin.

The new page is [here](http://www.sgh.geoffaweber.com/power-calculator/).

Comment: It seems you have a lot of syntax errors in the console. I'd start by fixing these

Comment: Are any standing out in particular? I'm only familiar with very basic javascript and am trying to navigate the code the other developer wrote.

Comment: Have you pasted the code into a wordpress page via their built-in editor? It may have added `<p>` and `</p>` on line returns. Gives you a lot of syntax errors.

Comment: Then you may have an iframe being blocked and a few 404 not found issues.

Comment: I did copy and paste into the built in editor. I'll take out all those <p> tags. It must have added those.

Comment: Capitalized title

Answer (score 0):

Take this snippet for example... Your including HTML within your `<script>` tag.
Remove all instances of `</p><p>`. It occurs a few times within your code.

```
<script></p>
    <p>function conHP100()
    {
    var kW = Number( document.getElementById( "input100" ).value );
    z=1.3404;
    HP100=kW*z;
    document.sizing.HP1.value=HP100;
    }</p>
    <p>function conHP200()
    {
    var kW = Number( document.getElementById( "input200" ).value );
    z=1.3404;
    HP200=kW*z;
    document.sizing.HP2.value=HP200;
    }</p>
    <p>function conHP300()
```